# Windows: How to cleanly stop tor process from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, tor

From time to time I need to stop `tor.exe` (Tor) using the command line while it is running on the background. So far I have tried the following:

- `C:\Path\to\tor.exe -system stop`, which doesn't work
- `C:\Path\to\tor.exe stop`, which doesn't work
- `net stop tor.exe`, which doesn't work
- `taskkill /f /im tor.exe`, which works but it doesn't seem to be clean.

I didn't found a general way to exit cleanly any `.exe` processes either.

What could I try?

Comment: Net stop service works. What error do you get ?

Comment: Does your TOR acts as service or as background application? If you need to stop the service then look for its correct name (use `sc query`, for example).

Comment: @John the error is something like the following : `System error 123 occurred.

Writing the file name, directory name, or label
volume is incorrect.` My computer is not in english so its just a translation.

Comment: The error points to a syntax error.  Are you sure it is a service you can stop and also have the correct service name?

Comment: @Akina to tell the truth I don't know the difference. The process is displayed in the task manager but all tor windows are closed. `sc query` didn't show the task manager process... weird

Comment: @John no I am not sure. About the name, I tried all `tor`, `tor.exe`, `C:\path\to\tor.exe`. The process name displayed is `tor.exe*32` so I tried that as well. What is the name for you?

Comment: *`sc query` didn't show the task manager process...* This command shows all services registered in the system - does TOR is absent in this list? Control panel - Services shows all services in the system - does TOR is absent in this list? If true then this is an application, and it cannot be unloaded via `net stop`.

Comment: [TOR User Manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) claims that the service can be installed/started/stopped/uninstalled via command line option. Stop service unloads its executable. Test `C:\Path\to\tor.exe --service stop`. But TOR have no the option for unloading the application.

Comment: @Akina I am on Windows 7, tor is absent in both lists. For the command i did a `sc query | findstr "tor"` but nothing interesting appeared. Control Panel - Services show only a bunch of Windows programs.

Comment: @Akina As for the tor manual I did both `tor --service remove` and `tor --service stop` but the process in the manager is still there. Actually by running them, a second process appears for a second and then it disappears

Comment: The service is not installed - so `net stop tor.exe`, `tor --service remove` and `tor --service stop` makes no sense. `taskkill` is the only option (of course the only within simple methods - you may unload it by a lot of another methods, for example, via WMI in VBS script/command form).

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot! I will try to install it or just add it to path. If I may ask a question further from the above. Is `taskkill` bad for my system? Is it bad If I use it pretty frequently?

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> If I may ask a question further from the above. Is taskkill bad for my system? Is it bad If I use it pretty frequently?

As long as you don't use `/f` it's no problem. Then what you're basically doing is asking the program "could you please shut down?". The program receives this signal and decides to act or not. A very typical thing that may happen is that you get a dialogue box with "Do you really want to quit?" or something like that. It's essentially the same as clicking the closing 'X' or pressing Alt-F4.

If you add `/f` it may be harmful in some cases, because that will forcibly kill the application. But on the other hand, if you cannot resolve the situation by invoking `taskkill` without the `/f` parameter, then the damage is often already done.

Usually, it's no big deal, but if you're unlucky, it could lead to things like corrupted files and such. But as long as you're only using user level applications, the risk of damaging your system as a whole is minimal. And I have a hard time believing that you could cause any major issues that cannot be resolved by just reinstalling Tor. I'd guess that the worst reasonably likely problems is things like corrupted downloaded files or something, but nothing major to the system.

#### TL;DR

`taskkill /f /im tor.exe` it NOT a clean way, but `taskkill /im tor.exe` is. But if the latter does not work, it's an indication that something is wrong, and it's possible that there simply is no clean way to do it.